# angular get selected value in multiple selects inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in my_array">
                        <td>
                            <select name='[{{$index}}].Name' > 
                                <option ng-repeat="sr in anotherArray" value="{{sr}}">
                                    {{sr}}
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </td> 
 </tr>
```

i have a table with rows populated by ng-repeat: **my_array**

there is another array : **anotherArray**

l want when the rows are repeated in angular for **my_array** to have its own value for **[{{$index}}].Name** to be based on the selected value for that particular row.

when l post the data to api **[{{$index}}].Name** will only have the same value even if l select different item for each rows.

l tried using ng-options as it was said its good for

of is there an easy way to get around it .

am populating the **anotherArray** and **anotherArray**

on different on same page but they are just an array with string values in it like as below

```
  $scope.anotherArray= [];

$scope.add = function () {
            $scope.errortext = "";
            if (!$scope.addMe) { return; }
            if ($scope.variants.indexOf($scope.addMe) == -1) {
                $scope.anotherArray.push($scope.addMe); 
            }
        }
```

the desired result is like

[image: desired table]

in image i_prepopulateOnRow1 ,i_prepopulateOnRow2 ...i_prepopulateOnRow upto Nth are add from **anotherArray**

when ever a new row from **my_array** is added it must have a select option for **anotherArray** thus in each row l can have value for i_prepopulateOnRow

the reason am using name as **[{{$index}}].Name** its becasue am posting to asp.net api.

the problem am facing is whenever l post all the rows have the same value for 
**[{{$index}}].Name** even if l select different values

**Edit two**

am not getting answers did l do it the wrong way /please even suggestion would help am two days stack on this. Help guys

Answer (score 0):

If you posting page on server side then HTML element name must be match with server class structure

```
Ex. Server class



public class otherClass
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class myclass
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

        public List<string> nameList { get; set; }

        public List<otherClass> otherList { get; set; }

    }

then you HTML elment name should be like



<form method="post" action="http://localhost:56096/api/Values">

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="text" name="nameList[0]" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" name="nameList[1]" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" name="nameList[2]" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="hidden" name="otherList[0].id" value="0" />
                <input type="text" name="otherList[0].name" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="hidden" name="otherList[1].id" value="1" />
                <input type="text" name="otherList[1].name" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="hidden" name="otherList[2].id" value="2" />
                <input type="text" name="otherList[2].name" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

I home may you get help from this

Thanks

Comment: thanks man the Server side classes are fine tested using static data and working but the issue is on client side ,the selected values are in the html l cannot get the angular to have selected value for the different rows being posted